# Openlayers: Is it possible to add a radius around a multipolygon?

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap, nominatim

I am using Openlayers and I would like to create a Multipolygon from a Multipolygon, that I got back from nominatim Geocode, but i would like to add some kind of radius around that multipolygon.

For Example: If I search for Munich I would like to show a multipolygon, that contains munich and 10km around the boundaries of Munich.

Do you have any tips on how I can approach this?

Comment: JSTS will buffer OpenLayers geometries, example at https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/jsts.html  Note the buffer is in projection units, depending on the projection you will need to adjust for point resolution.

Comment: @Mike thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for!